# I'm currently learning Ruby from Codecademy and I'm not sure if this works, according to the website it's right but I don't see how?

Tags: ruby

so the assignment is I'm making a case statement and adding movies paired with their rating in a hash. The "add" case is supposed to add a prompted movie with its paired rating to a hash. It's also supposed to check if the movie already exists in the hash and prompts the user if it does. There's an "update" case which allows the user to update a movie within the hash and also checks if the user inputs a movie that isn't in the hash. Now the update case works fine, it lets the user know if the movies doesn't exist however, I don't think the else part of the add case is working properly? I can add "Wall-E" with a rating of 10 and it doesn't prompt me saying it's already there.

```
movies = {
  "Wall-E" => 10
}
puts "Please choose to add, update, display or delete movies"
choice = gets.chomp

case choice 
  when "add" 
     puts "Please name a movie you wish to add"
     title = gets.chomp
     puts "Please give a rating for this movie"
     rating = gets.chomp
     if movies[title.to_sym].nil? == true
        movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
        puts "#{title} was added with a rating of #{rating}"
      else  
      puts "The movie you entered has already been added"
    end

when "update"
    puts "Please name a movie you wish to update"
    title = gets.chomp
    if movies[title].nil? == true 
      puts "Hey bud, that one doesn't exist but you can add it if you want"
      else 
      puts "Please give a rating for this movie" 
      rating = gets.chomp
      movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
    end
```

Comment: An empty string is not nil. Check for `title.empty?` instead.

Comment: @ZamanZaidi: Aside from what ToddAJacobs correctly said, testing something for `== true` is not particularily elegant (although there are cases where you need this this construct).  Try to avoid it.

Comment: Right I see now thanks a lot one question though @user1934428 What should I do instead, what would classify as elegant?

Comment: If you just want to test truishness, do something like `if movies[title.to_sym].nil?` or `if movies[title.to_sym].empty?`, depending what you want to test. If you start comparing to `true`, where does it end? Maybe you do a `if (a>b)==true`, but then, you go on doing a `if ((a>b)==true) == true` and so on. Everything correct, but needless complex, `if a>b` would do as well. You may consider comparing to `true` if, for instance, you have a value which may be either `true` or `false` or some other data type. But in those situation, a `case` is often clearer than an `if`.